# Saving records in MySQL which does not pre-exist

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

Let say, I have a pre-defined table called `cities`, with almost all the cities in my country.

When a user register himself (user table), the column `cities_id` in the table `user` stores the city id from the table `cities` (Foreign Key, reference table cities), something like

```
CREATE TABLE `cities` (
    `id` int,
    `city_name` varchar(100)
)

CREATE TABLE `user` (
    `id` int,
    `name` varchar(60)
    `****`
    `cities_id` FK
)
```

The user table stores the city id.

But what if I missed a few cities ... How does the user then save his city name in the user table which does not accept any city name but only IDs.

Can I have one more column `city_name` right after the cities_id in the table `user` something like

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
    `id` int,
    `name` varchar(60)
    `****`
    `cities_id` FK
    `citiy name` varchar(100)
)
```

to record the data entered by the user at the time of registration? Can this be done?

Comment: The user can’t unless the user also can create a new city in the `cities` table

Comment: @Jaokim Danielson, how does facebook do this? When you fill the city column it suggest you cities name and if it does not exist you get to write your own. I believe FB stores the city ID cz when you click the city hyperlink in a profile it shows interesting places related to that cities

Comment: Well your question is very broad and it's unclear how you want to solve this, in the client code, in server-side code or completely in sql? But the basic logic is very simple, if the city doesn't exist then store it and used the new id for that city when storing the user.

Comment: Do you want to allow users to enter arbitrary data in cities table (and make all sort of typos, duplicates or made-up/unofficial names)? I would rather suggest that you download the data from some official/well maintained source so that the probability of someone not finding their city name is minimal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add a type to city table tag, the user can't find their corresponding to the city allows him to type the name of his city, and then you in the city, and will create a corresponding record in the table type marked as a special status (convenient operating personnel check and correction), at the same time to save the record id to the user record

```
CREATE TABLE `cities` (
    `id` int,
    `city_name` varchar(100),
    `type` int,
)

CREATE TABLE `user` (
    `id` int,
    `name` varchar(60)
    `****`
    `cities_id` FK
)
```

Comment: I like this idea, I'm geeking out over an imagined CMS that allows you to approve, edit, combine and reject user suggested cities :)

Answer (score 3):

As @Joakim mentioned in the comment, from a DB perspective, as cities_id is a foreign key referencing to the cities table, inserting a record to the user table will fail if the city in question is not already there in the table.

From a programming perspective, if you want a city which is not there in the table should be first inserted automatically whenever a user is registering, it is possible. Assuming you are using Java and Hibernate and User entity contains City entity, then calling saveOrUpdate() method on the user entity will cause the city record to be inserted if not already there, and a user record will then be inserted into the User table.

Comment: https://www.journaldev.com/3481/hibernate-session-merge-vs-update-save-saveorupdate-persist-example

Comment: that is java and hibernate ... anything in line with php and mysql?

Answer (score 3):

That's how I would *quickly* solve this

Create an additional table to store the missing cities, that will be introduced by users

```
CREATE TABLE `cities_users` (
`id` int,
`city_name` varchar(100),
`added_by` varchar(100),
`added_TS` DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

Create a VIEW that UNION the 2 cities tables :

```
CREATE VIEW all_cities AS
SELECT id, city_name FROM `cities`
UNION ALL
SELECT id, city_name FROM `cities_users`;
```

Whenever a user  register, you query the VIEW to check if the user's city exists. That way you'll kknow if a city exists in your original table OR the cities introduced by users.

If not, you INSERT the new city in the `cities_users` table (along with the user that created it for logging purposes).

You should generate a unique ID properly, ie one that can't ever exists in the *cities* table. You can do this in various ways, here's a quick example : Take the last ID in the cities_users table and add 1 million to it. Your cities_users IDs will be like: 1000001, 1000002, 1000003

And finally, you insert the generated cities_users ID in the users table.

Having a separate table for user inputs should help you to keep the database clean :

1. Your original cities table remains totally unchanged
2. You will know easily at all times the new cities added by whom and when, and you can create a small interface to review and manage that.
3. Your users are working for you to complete your database.

Comment: thank you buddy, your suggestion makes a lot of sense. I would like to try your solution before I accept your answer. Pls give a me a day or two. I'll revert quick. Thank you again.

Comment: For even simpler usage, insertion of missing cities into `cities_user` could be automated using a `TRIGGER` when a new user registers with an unknown city. That would save you querying the view in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

If a user suggest a new city you should create a new record into cities table and store city_id into users table. This is the best way to store the table records.

Comment: I do not want to lose a user just because his city wasn't already in my records and this is what I am trying to solve. If the user's city isn't in my record I still want him to add his city. Many people will tend to forget that they made a request and wont come back. I find Thomas G. answer much inline to what I am looking for. Thank you for your suggestion though.

Comment: i was not asking to loos a user as the user is the very valuable asset. I was asking to add city first then use it's id into user users table along with user details. if you add in two tables you will face a problem while performing a search from the cities table.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like it should be pointed out, despite answers to the contrary, that your original suggestion of adding a `city_name` column to the table will work fairly well

If you allow both `cities_id` and `city_name` to be nullable then you can validate that one and only one of them is set in the application logic

The benefit of this approach is that it would keep your city table 'pure' and allow you to count duplicates of and analyse the user supplied cities easily

It would however add a very sparse nullable `city_name` column in your table

I guess it depends on how you want to get the city from the user, (drop-down + text box for others, text-box with suggestions, just a text box) and what you plan to do with the cities you have gathered

You could even change the label to 'city (or nearest city)' with a hard-coded drop-down, or searchable drop-down, and not allow user supplied cities

Answer (score 0):

If you have a buffer table where the raw data is put in, i.e. the relationship between city_name, user_name

```
CREATE TABLE `buffer_city_user` (
`buffer_id` int,
`city_name` varchar(100),
`user_name` varchar(100),
);
```

you can first process the buffer table for new city_names - if found, insert into table cities.

Then insert the user info - any new city-names should already be in the cities table and no foreign key issues will occur.